# Select By Attribute Query Using Shape Area

Tags: arcpy, arcmap

I have a script that assigns a rank to each feature in a feature class based on the sort order of a target field. When I use this script to assign a rank based on shape area, I cannot pull the full shape area using SearchCursor and getValue (I get 8 decimal places, instead of 13), so my queries never end up selecting any features. Is there a way to get the full float for the shape area? For now my work around is to create a new field that has the shape area rounded to 6 digits, and rank features based on that.

```
targetField = "Shape_Area"

#build list of unique vals
qRows = arcpy.SearchCursor(inLayer)
for row in qRows:
    uVal = row.getValue(targetField)
    if uVal not in uList:
        uList.append(uVal)
#sort list
uList.sort()

for val in uList:
    qry = '"' + targetField + '" = {}'.format(val)

# make selection based on qry
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("inLayer_lyr", "NEW_SELECTION", qry)
```

Comment: First off, ditch the use of *old-style* cursors. All new code should use `arcpy.da.SearchCursor` and if only the area is wanted, list `[´shape@area´]`as the column list. Since this returns an array of arrays you can use a list comprehension and sort that (or specify an ORDER BY)

Comment: Thanks. This is an old script that I haven't gotten around to updating, and it's the first time it's been used to sort on the shape area. The target field is chosen from a dropdown in a custom tool - so it doesn't come through as [´shape@area´]. I could add in a block to handle it that way should someone choose shape area. Is there no way to get the full value for the shape area short of that?

Comment: And what type is the `Shape_area` field? If it's `float` you already have the full value (all that's there)

Comment: shape area is a double. my current query prints out (e.g.) as "Shape_Area" = 1745.453180697, but the full value is 1745.4531869738764, so my query isn't selecting any features.

Comment: It is not possible to reliably query double values without bracketing them with an epsilon; some IEEE values cannot be represented as strings and returned to an equivalent byte pattern. This is a fact of binary computing.

Comment: Thanks, @Vince - that seems to be the crux of the issue.

Answer (score 3):

If you are ok with rounding, and what you are trying to do is to not have to add a new field and calculate as rounded values you can do something like below. Round the coordinates returned by the [da.SearchCursor](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-data-access/searchcursor-class.htm) (dont use old cursors) to match the ones you want to select:

```
import arcpy
fc = 'Buildings'
areas = [12175.3, 2313.9]
decimals = 1

#areas = [round(area,decimals) for area in areas] #If you also want to round "input areas"

oids = tuple([i[0] for i in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc,['OID@','SHAPE@AREA']) if round(i[1],decimals) in areas])
oidfield = arcpy.Describe(fc).OIDFieldName
sql = "{0} IN{1}".format(arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(fc,oidfield), oids)
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(in_layer_or_view=fc, 
                                       where_clause=sql)
```

[image]